# How do I suspend / sleep while bluetooth is active?

Tags: linux, bluetooth, suspend

I cannot suspend / sleep while bluetooth is active. There is no error message in the syslog.

However, after `rfkill block bluetooth` I can sucessfully sleep / suspend.

I use a bluetooth mouse so permanently disabling bluetooth is not an option.

How can I sleep / suspend while still having bluetooth functionality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Cause

Kernel [Bug 200039 - BT advertising packet wakes up the system from S3 and suspend-to-idle](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=200039).

This affects Intel (`8087:0aaa`) and Atheros (`0cf3:e005`)(`0cf3:e007`) bluetooth:

- Acer Swift SF314-55
- Asus UX333FA
- Asus UX433FN
- Asus UX533FD

#### Workaround

A workaround is to automatically deauthorise the bluetooth USB device before sleep/suspend, and then reauthorise upon wake.

For `systemd` work-around is to use the following:

`/etc/systemd/system/bluetooth-disable-before-sleep.service` (note the CHANGE ME lines):

```
[Unit]
Description=disable bluetooth for systemd sleep/suspend targets
Before=sleep.target
Before=suspend.target
Before=hybrid-sleep.target
Before=suspend-then-hibernate.target
StopWhenUnneeded=yes

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

# Usage: bluetooth-sleep (start|stop) <vendor> <product>
# Get values from `lsusb`:
# eg: Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp.
# Usage: bluetooth-sleep (start|stop) 8087 0aaa

##### CHANGE ME: (the two hex values at end of next line) ###
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/bluetooth-sleep start 8087 0aaa
##### CHANGE ME: (the two hex values at end of next line) ###
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/bluetooth-sleep  stop  8087 0aaa

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
WantedBy=suspend.target
WantedBy=hybrid-sleep.target
WantedBy=suspend-then-hibernate.target
```

`/usr/local/bin/bluetooth-sleep`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Disable bluetooth given first argument "start"
# Re-enable bluetooth given first argument "stop"
# Expects vendor and product as 2nd and 3rd arguments

set -eu

usage() {
  script_name=${0##*/}
  printf '%s: de-authorise bluetooth during sleep/suspend\n' "$script_name" >&2
  printf 'Usage: %s (start|stop) <vendor> <product>\n' "$script_name" >&2
  exit 1
}

case "${1:-}" in
  start) value=0 ;;
  stop)  value=1 ;;
  *)     usage   ;;
esac

[ $# -ne 3 ] && usage
vendor=$2
product=$3

shopt -s nullglob
for dir in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*; do
  if [[ -L "$dir" && -f $dir/idVendor && -f $dir/idProduct &&
        $(cat "$dir/idVendor")  == "$vendor" &&
        $(cat "$dir/idProduct") == "$product" ]]; then
    echo "$value" > "$dir/authorized"
    echo "echo $value > $dir/authorized"
  fi
done
```

Credit to [this post](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/cannot-suspend-without-rfkill-block-bluetooth/101542/9?u=ataraxy).

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it is working. Don't forget to remove `### CHANGE ME ###` as comments also treated as command line arguments.

Though running `/usr/local/bin/bluetooth-sleep stop 8087 0029` or `echo 0 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-14/authorized` manually works unstable on my system. Bluetooth may suddenly stop working after disabling and re-enabling device, echo with stream redirect may block forever preventing sleep job from completion, after that even `systemctl reboot` may stop working. Looks like there's some another hardware or kernel/module bugs :(

Comment: Cheers @StanislavMamontov, I moved the `# CHANGE ME`s to a separate line.

Comment: I had to disable this "fix", it was a bit unstable on my laptop (BT device on my thinkpad is USB 8087:0029). But it looks like the problem is gone after recent updates!

Comment: You also need to `/usr/local/bin/bluetooth-sleep` executable, reload systemd with `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and enable the service with `sudo systemctl enable bluetooth-disable-before-sleep.service`